# Why is the cache size half of what it should be as reported by /proc/cpuinfo?

Tags: command-line, cpu

/proc/cpuinfo shows the cache size to be 4MB but the specs on the intel site show the cache to be 8MB.  Any ideas as to why? I'm using 32-bit ubuntu 10.04.

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -iE "processor|physical id|cache size"
processor   : 0
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
processor   : 1
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
processor   : 2
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
processor   : 3
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
```

http://ark.intel.com/products/29765/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q6600-%288M-Cache-2_40-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Intel Core 2 has cores clustered by 2. Each core has its own very fast level 1 cache (L1) and each cluster features a shared L2 cache.

So the 8MB are actually shared between 2 cores, you have a total of 16MB, 8 to each 2 cores, have a look at this

http://jerome.berbiqui.org/parallel-many-core-CS/article001.png

source: http://jerome.berbiqui.org/parallel-many-core-CS/